# For a general norm on $\mathbb{R}^d$, how can the intersection of a ball's boundary and a cone be contained in a $(d-1)$-hyperplane?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, euclidean-geometry, normed-spaces, convex-hulls

Consider $\mathbb{R}^d$ under a general norm (not necessarily Euclidean). Consider two fixed concentric balls centered at the origin $B(0, R_1)$ and $B(0, R_1/2)$. Let $x$ be an arbitrary point with $|x| > R_1 > 0$ and $N_x$ be the $(d-1)$-hyperplane containing $x$ that is perpendicular to the line through $x$ and the origin. $C'_x$ is the convex hull of $\left\{ x\right\} \cup B(0,R_1/2)$.

Let $B$ denote some ball $B(x,r)$ with $r > 0$ centered at $x$. It is stated that $N$ is the "hyperplane" parallel to $N_x$ that contains $ \partial B \cap C'_x$.

How, in general, can it be true that such an $N$ exists? Taking the particular case of the euclidean norm on $\mathbb{R}^3$ as an illustration, it is *not* true that $\partial B \cap C'_x$ is contained in a $(d-1)$-hyperplane.

Comment: I hope I'm not missing anything obvious

Comment: I am convinced it does not exist, based on the fact that balls are convex for any norm.

Comment: @Strichcoder It's in a published paper (cited by big names) though.... I couldn't find any corrections for that paper. It doesn't affect the results proven therein so maybe that's how it passed under the radar. But I have to be certain there's something I'm not seeing.

Comment: Can you point me to the paper?

Comment: @Strichcoder http://www.math.unt.edu/~mauldin/papers/no106.pdf Lemma 3.1

Comment: From what I understand, Lemma 3.1 in the paper states that $\partial B$ has Hausdorff dimension $d-1$ (or possibly higher). In relation to your question, yes, $\partial B$ can be $d-1$-dimensional, but not a $d-1$-dimensional hyperplane. The hyperplane is flat, but the boundary of a convex ball is not. There are lots of concepts of dimensionality. Vectorspaces can have dimensions, manifolds can have dimensions, measurable sets can have (Hausdoff)-dimension. Maybe I am  missing your point though.

Comment: @Strichcoder I agree with you, that is my view too. But in the proof the authors construct a "hyperplane" containing part of $\partial B$, which does not make sense to me, at all, for precisely the reasons you have stated. This was the point behind my question. I would appreciate if someone points me towards an alternate proof of that Lemma that does not contain typos/ errors.

Comment: I am trying to re-write the proof of Lemma 3.1 by taking the maximal _Euclidean_ ball nested within the $R_1/2$-radius ball around the origin under the general norm and defining $C'_x$ as the convex hull of $x$ and said Euclidean ball.  Then $\partial C'_x \cap \partial B$ is contained within a $(d-1)$-hyperplane normal to $x$.